# Angular5 Observables are not working

Tags: angular, components, observable

In the #headerComponent is a input-field for my search. When a user executes the search, the searchquery is send by `#websocketsService` to a node-server and gets a JSON result back.

This result should trigger a method of `#graphComponent`.

I have read that it is a good practice to have another service to handle this, so I have created `#dataService` for that, this is where I handle the observables.

So the flow is:

*headerComponent -> (triggers) #websocketService -> (search query to) node.js-Server -> (result back to) #websocketService -> (set var in) #dataService -> (trigger method of) #graphcomponent (with fresh data from #dataService)*

All works fine, except that I can't get the method in `#graphComponent` triggered.

## dataService

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/**
 * This Service is for keep, simple and small Data sharing
 * to communicate between components
 */
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

private subject = new Subject<any>();

public setGraphData(data) {
   console.log('setGraphData:' + data);
   this.subject.next({text: data});
}

public getGraphData(): Observable<any> {
   console.log('get graphDataSubject');
   return this.subject.asObservable();
}

constructor() { }
}
```

## graphComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data/data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'graph',
  templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.scss'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit{ 

  graphData: Observable<any>;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor( private _dataService: DataService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this._dataService.getGraphData().subscribe(graphData => {
      console.log('PLEASE TRIGGER ME WHEN graphData IS UPDATED');
    });
  } 

// PLEASE TRIGGER THIS FUNCTION WHEN NEW graphData IS SET
triggerMe() {
    console.log('WORKS')
}       
}
```

## websocketService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { DataService } from '../data/data.service';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketsService {
  private _search: string;
  private url: string;
  public wsConnection: WebSocket;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
    this.url = 'ws://localhost:1337';
  }

 /*
  * creates connection, sends query and maps ws-handler
  */
  sendQuery(search: string) {

    this._search = search;
    console.log('Perform search for: ' + this._search);
    this.wsConnection = new WebSocket(this.url);
    this.wsConnection.onopen = () => this.wsConnection.send(JSON.stringify({ data: this._search }));
    this.wsConnection.onerror = event => console.log('A Error has occured!');
    this.wsConnection.onclose = event => console.log('Connection closed');
    this.wsConnection.onmessage = (event) => {
      // SEND NEW DATA TO OBSERVABLE      
      this._dataService.sendGraphData(event.data);
    };
  }
}
```

I just can't get it running, that when new `graphData` is set in the #dataService, the `triggerMe()` in #graphComponent is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning an Observable to an Observable.

`graphData` in your data service is an Observable, and in your component, you're setting the viewmodel property `graphData`, which is also an Observable, to the Observerable returned by the service.

Instead, you need to set the viewmodel value type equal to what the websocket is going to return, like `string` or `object`, or punt and use `any`.

I've changed a few names around, and created a sample project for this. Here's a link to the source code: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aun50jHsxPB0gcd4emGcDqViLGbySw

The data service remains unchanged, but I changed the socket service to hit an echo service on the web for demonstration:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  public wsConnection: WebSocket;

  url: string;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
    this.url = 'ws://echo.websocket.org/';
  }

 /*
  * creates connection, sends query and maps ws-handler
  */
  sendQuery(): void {

    this.wsConnection = new WebSocket(this.url);
    this.wsConnection.onopen = () => this.wsConnection.send('Test Message');
    this.wsConnection.onerror = event => console.log('A Error has occured!');
    this.wsConnection.onclose = event => console.log('Connection closed');
    this.wsConnection.onmessage = (event) => {
      this._dataService.setGraphData(event.data);
    };
  }
}
```

I just leveraged the app.component.ts created by Angular CLI in this example component to get the value from the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { SocketService } from './socket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    Graph Data: {{ data }}
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  data: any; // <-- not an Observable
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor (
    private dataService: DataService,
    private socketService: SocketService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get the data from the socket service
    this.socketService.sendQuery();

    this.subscription = this.dataService.getGraphData().subscribe(graphData => {
      // set the value in the viewmodel with the data from the service
      this.data = graphData.text;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

First, install dependencies, then run the sample code with: `ng serve`, and you'll see the value echoed back from the service.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer.. but it doesn't work :/  ..  I follow the data-stream with console.log() and everything looks fine..  except the subscribers, they are not beeing triggered/informed .. as in your example, in the `this.subscription = this.dataService.getGraphData().subscribe(....)` i also do a `console.log('success')`, but nothing happens ..

Comment: it works when I run the code. I'll make another example that accepts a form input, then pings the websocket and binds the echoed value back to the template when the state changes.

Comment: @Mka24 See this updated project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aun50jHsxPB0gcd56JPGHlFajqkiJg for an example that accepts input from a form, passes it to the websocket and then sets the value into the Observable.

Comment: Hi, thank you :) .. it did't workt immediately when I have adapted it to my project, but your answer is 100% correct. I did get it working now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad you were able to get it working.